# How to get the status of an Order on any resource using IBM cloud through Softlayer Rest API?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

For Example if I order a Private Vlan,how do I confirm whether order Succeeded\In progress\Failed.I didn't find any API references related to get Success.

Answer (score 0):

To know if the order was provisioned successfully see the following detail.

if '**provisionDate**' is null and '**activeTransactions**' is not empty, the provisioning is in progress.

if '**provisionDate**' is not null and '**activeTransactions**' is an empty array, the provisioning is over.

Use the next requests for following the attributes pointed out lately.

Hardware

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Hardware/1111/getObject?objectMask=mask[activeTransactions]
```

Change 1111 by HardwareId valid

VirtualGuest

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/1111/getObject?objectMask=mask[activeTransactions]
```

Change 1111 by VirtualGuestId valid

Comment: Thanks for reply Daniel. But I got error While trying that api.I ordered Public Vlan and that vlan ID i used error through "{"error":"Unable to find object with id of '2617255'.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_ObjectNotFound"}"

Comment: Try following the next example for vlans
_https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkVlans?objectMask=mask[id,billingItem[id,orderItem[id,order[id]]]]&objectFilter={"networkVlans": {"billingItem":{"orderItem":{"order":{"id":{"operation": 99999}}}}}}_

change the 99999 data with orderId from order response